# Access related database field Django template

Tags: django, templates

I'm sure there's an answer to this question already but I can't find one...

I have two Models like so:

```
class TwitterAccount(models.Model):
    facebookaccount = models.ForeignKey(FacebookAccount)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    twitter_id = models.CharField(max_length=28)
    icon_url = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)


class Tweet(models.Model):
    twitteraccount = models.ForeignKey(TwitterAccount)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tweet_content = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

I have a view like this:

```
def account_history(request):
    user = request.user
    tweets_p = Tweet.objects.filter(user_id=user.id).order_by('-pub_date')
    paginator = Paginator(tweets_p, 15)

    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        tweets = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        tweets = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        tweets = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'account_history.html', {"tweets": tweets})
```

And a template like this:

```
{% for tweet in tweets %}
    {{ tweet.username }}
    {{ tweet.tweet_content }}
    {{ TwitterAccount.icon_url }} # How do I access this value?
{% endfor %}
```

How would I access the related TwitterAccount.icon_url within a for loop and in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a simple

```
{{tweet.twitteraccount.icon_url}}
```

which would show on the template if present.

To display the icon on the template:

```
<img src="{{tweet.twitteraccount.icon_url}}" alt="Some alt text" />
```

Documentation on this can be [found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#accessing-method-calls)